# Sourcemap was invalid or not parseable in Sentry

Tags: javascript, source-maps, sentry

I am facing strange behavior from sentry. I use sentry-webpack-plugin to upload my sourcemaps to remote company sentry server. Everything seems to be allright.
[I see sourcemaps under artifacts in release tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAqEd.png)

But the thing is, that in some cases soursemaps are mapped correctly, but in other sentry shows minified error code with warning **"Sourcemap was invalid or not parseable"** (Even on the same error)

I did a little research, on sentry forum some pointed that it could be because of gzipped sourcemap when uploading artifact. But why then in some cases it works, and not works in others?

Here is example: one error appear two times in sentry, but first is mapped correctly to sources, second is not

**Valid mapping:**

[Mapped exception from sentry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDacT.png)

**Invalid mapping:**

[NOT mapped exception from sentry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOBfT.png)

In the main.js last line is:

//#sourceMappingURL=vendor.d5b6708d.js.map

My source maps are uploaded to sentry, and the deleted from static server which serves main.*.js via WebpackDeleteAfterEmit plugin.

Comment: I have the same issue